# How to format number with hyphens in gsp?

Tags: groovy, gsp

Currently I have a sortCode `123456` and I would like this thing to be formatted into `12-34-56` in gsp file without using the controller.

Code, where the result is `12,34,56`

```
<g:formatNumber number="${sortCode}" format="##,##" />
```

Any way to use replaceAll on the above code for example? Or the only way is to use the controller?

Comment: It will be good to convert / format your expected data at controller and then render it to gsp, don't make gsp code complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
${g.formatNumber( [number: "${sortCode}", format: "##,##" ] ).replaceAll( ',', '-' )}
```

The above will fail if `sortCode` is null/empty so best to protect with `<g:if...`